# Weight painting without changing vertex group

Tags: materials, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I use vertex groups for material assignment, besides just weights. I'd have a vertex group "Arm_L", then assign the vertices of the left arm to it.

But to make things look good I have to weight paint some other parts too, maybe from the shoulder. This adds vertices of the shoulder to my Arm_L group, which in turn messes with my materials.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can't you add a second group and assign it to the same arm, then use that one for your materials and the first one for the weights? ) I have to admit I've not used groups that way, but it seems to work ok.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weight paint uses Vertex groups to work, all the vertices that you affect in weight paint will be added to the vertex group that you're working on.

I suggest that you use other way to separate materiales, if you were using vertex groups you should be able to use materials by faces too, by going into edit mode and assigning the materials (this won't affect vertex groups/weight paint).

If there's an specific reason to use only vertex groups for your materials i suggest you use more Vertex Groups, some ONLY for weight paint/deformation, and others for ONLY material data.